# Import podcast into itunes programmatically

Tags: cocoa, applescript, itunes, podcast

I am developing an application to create audio podcasts (.m4a files). I have been trying to figure out if it's possible to automatically import the podcasts that my user creates into iTunes, and have it show up in the podcasts category. Can this be done in Cocoa, or via AppleScript?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to create a rss feed and host it somewhere (so that it can be reached via http). You can host it on your localhost, for example.
Than, when your user is adding a file to directory you can run some script, that will add a feed item to your rss file.

In iTunes your can add your podcast rss feed via: File > Subscript to Podcast...
The rest iTunes will do for you.

Comment: He probably built some sort of podcast hosting solution. That is why he wants to publish RSS programatically.